# Отмена подписки лямбда метода от события

Tags: c#, события

Всем привет, прохожу курс по c#

имеется строка:

```
// Невозможно открепить ранее присоединенный анонимный метод.
        instance.MyEvent -= delegate { Console.WriteLine("Анонимный метод 1."); };
```

как отмечено автором курса - Невозможно открепить ранее присоединенный анонимный метод

но, через некоторое время вносится поправка на то, что анонимный метод выступающий обработчиком события - открепить все же можно, но "... эту технику открепления вы увидите в следующем курсе" .

Возникает вопрос:

1) **почему** не срабатывает вышеприведенный метод открепления лямбда метода?

2) **как** открепить лямбда метод?

3)Если открепить лямбда метод не так просто, то можно ли (я не помню точно принимает ли лямбда метод параметры в конструктор) в его конструктор передать вызов например какого-нибудь другого обычного , например созданного нами "зловредного" метода(который будет делать какую-то пакость), который будет вызываться на это событие  - через лямбда метод - вызываемый этим событием? Например при событии - "нажатие мышкой" (написанного нами а не  готовым(стандартным) если таково имеется) - через лямбда метод вызвать какой-то "зловредный метод"

Comment: Мне кажется, не стоит заниматься по видеоурокам. Лучше книг ничего не бывает.

Answer (score 6):

1. Вы должны при отписке указать тот же обработчик, что и при подписке. Если вы напишете

   ```
   instance.MyEvent += delegate { Console.WriteLine("Анонимный метод 1."); };
   instance.MyEvent -= delegate { Console.WriteLine("Анонимный метод 1."); };
   ```

   — то второй строке вы попытаетесь отписать *новый* делегат, не совпадающий с делегатом из первой строки (каждая конструкция вида `delegate { ... }` создаёт новый делегат). Так что отписаться не выйдет.
2. Открепить очень просто. Запишите ваш обработчик в переменную:

   ```
   EventDelegate handler = delegate { Console.WriteLine("Анонимный метод 1."); };
   instance.MyEvent += handler;

   ...

   instance.MyEvent -= handler;
   ```

   При необходимости запомните `handler` в поле вашего класса.
3. Да, конечно. Внутри делегата-подписчика может быть любой код, сколь угодно зловредный. Вы как программист отвечаете за то, чтобы знать, какой код зловредный а какой нет, и не запускать зловредный код. (Или запускать, если вы так хотите.)

---

Кстати, запись в виде `delegate { ... }` — очень древний синтаксис. Сейчас так никто не пишет, а пользуются лямбда-нотацией: `() => Console.WriteLine("Анонимный метод 1.")`.